# SpringBoot WAR file deployed into Tomcat running but still returning 404

Tags: spring-boot, war, tomcat9

I want to demonstrate a simple SpringBoot application being deployed into a separately running Tomcat instance. Even though my application appears to have been deployed, I cannot access it in Tomcat.

I have followed the 'Traditional deployment' instructions in the Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html).

I have tried using a different version of Tomcat and running the war file as `ROOT.war`but get similar behaviour.

When I run the war standalone e.g. `java -jar build/libs/springbootify.war` I can successfully access the expected URL `http://localhost:8080/doit`.

**Application.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**MyController.java**

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/doit")
    public String getSomething() {
        return "Something";
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
    id 'com.palantir.docker-run' version '0.22.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
}
```

See the reproducible example on [Github](https://github.com/tkgregory/springbootify/tree/stackoverflow).

I can see that the war file has been deployed in the Tomcat logs

```
29-Jun-2019 17:07:04.434 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/springbootify.war] has finished in [857] ms
```

However, when I access `http://localhost:8080/springbootify/doit` I get a 404 response.

I expect this to return the string "something" with a 200 response.

**UPDATE - 2019-07-12**

I have tried building the war using Maven, and manually deploying to Tomcat via the manager UI and this works correctly

Inspecting the difference between the war files generated by Gradle and Maven I found the following:

1) Maven adds these additional attributes to the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 12
Implementation-Title: springbootify
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

2) Maven adds this additional library to the war:

`WEB-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar` whereas in the Gradle war it is in `WEB-INF/lib-provided/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar`

I'm going to suppose it's one of these reasons that it's not working with Gradle, but so far I haven't managed to modify the Gradle generated war to include these differences.

The newly added `pom.xml` can also be viewed on the provided [Github link](https://github.com/tkgregory/springbootify).

Comment: I used gradle to build a war from that github repo and installed it in a tomcat9 instance.  That URL returns "something" for me.  Does http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list show the application as running for you?

Comment: I just tried the same using Tomcat 9 service in Windows. http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list is showing the application as running, but http://localhost:8080/springbootify/doit is still returning 404.

Comment: It's possible the context root is different when you installed it.  What is the "Path" displayed for springbootify on localhost:8080/manager/html/list?

Comment: The context root is localhost:8080/springbootify. Only thing I noticed is that there is no `org.springframework` logging coming out, so I'm not convinced it's properly installed. Then again, there's no error logging either.